# Need help finishing the code for these two activities?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working on an android app that launches two activities using the on click listener everything in my code checks out fine except where the `public void onClick(View v)` begins I have multiple errors starting on that line and I am unable to run the code? I would kindly appreciate any help as I am fairly new to this. My code is as follows

```
public class Safaricom extends Activity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.safaricom);

          Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
          Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

          button1.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
          button2.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
      }

      private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent intent = null;
                  switch(v.getId()){
                  case R.id.button1: 
                       intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
                       break;
                  case R.id.button2:
                       intent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
                       break;
                  }
                  if (intent != null)
                      this.startActivity(intent);
             }     
      }; 
}
```

The Errors are at two points.
First where it says `public void on click view` ( The Error is - `Multiple Markers at this line - implements android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick- The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass` )

Second where it says `this.startActivity(intent);` (The Error is -T`he method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}`)

Comment: Provide more information about the errors.

Comment: I added the errors below the code

Comment: I have managed to finish it thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this` use `v.getContext()` or `YOUR_ACTIVITY.this`

Actually If you read the Docs carefully, you will know that `Intent` parameters contain `Activity` so when you are using `this` it means that you are giving a parameter of type `new View.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can see right off a couple of errors.  To make it clearer since it apparently was not clear by simply looking at the code and learning.  I added Safaricom.this in each of the new Intent statements.  This is because the Intent constructor needs a Context as the first argument and an OnClickListener is not a Context, you need to ge the enclosing Activity which is a context.  One other edit, I missed, the startActivity also needs to have Safaricom prepended.

```
public class Safaricom extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.safaricom);

      Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

      button1.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
      button2.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
  }

  private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = null;
              switch(v.getId()){
              case R.id.button1: 
                   intent = new Intent(Safaricom.this, Second.class);
                   break;
              case R.id.button2:
                   intent = new Intent(Safaricom.this, SignUp.class);
                   break;
              }
              if (intent != null)
                  Safaricom.this.startActivity(intent);
         }     
     };
 }
```

Comment: Where are the errors? What have you fixed? You just pasted in a wall of code.

Comment: Is it that hard to see? He just used the reference to your activity called `Safaricom.this` in the Intents. You should also call `Safaricom.this.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: Yes, it was hard to see. Pasting in 32 lines of code directly copied from the question, with two small changes and no description of what or where the changes are, is not a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks I got the Safaricom.this.startActivity(intent) part I only have one error left where it says  public void onClick(View v) { --->The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method

Comment: Are you using Java 6?  Java 5 does not allow the @Override annotation on abstract base methods.

Comment: I removed the @Override annotation and it worked fine am using eclipse

Comment: Well, that is fine, but in the project properties, if you make sure you are using Java 6, then the @Override should work.  If you are already using Java 6 and the Override is a problem, then there might be another error.  Anyway, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error

```
The Error is - Multiple Markers at this line - implements android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick- The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass )
```

Try removing the @override

If that doesn't remove the second error then let us know if there is a different issue arising.